# Contradictory "missing lifetime specifier" error on owned value

Tags: rust, lifetime

I wrote code to model the following structure, where a node has a reference to its parent node:

```
struct Node<'a> {
    parent: &'a Node,
}

impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    fn new(parent: &'a Node) -> Node {
        Node { parent }
    }
}
```

I thought with the lifetime parameter on the `parent` attribute and on the `parent` parameter in the `new` function it is made clear that the value behind the reference to `parent` has to live at least as long as the child node that holds the reference.

However, the compiler gives me two "`missing lifetime specifier`" messages.

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:2:17
  |
7 |     parent: &'a Node,
  |                 ^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

There **is** a lifetime parameter on the attribute. What the hell does the compiler want from me here?

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:6:33
  |
6 |     fn new(parent: &'a Node) -> Node {
  |                                 ^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Here I expected the compiler to assume that the return value has to live at least as long as `'a`. Appearantly it does not. I thought it is syntactically impossible (because unnecessary) to annotate an owned value with a lifetime parameter. But still the compiler seemed to desire one here so I gave what it was asking for.

```
// --snip
fn new(parent: &'a Node) -> 'a Node {
// --snip
```

When I tried to compile that, the second error turned into a differnt one:

```
error: expected type, found `'a`
 --> src/main.rs:6:33
  |
6 |     fn new(parent: &'a Node) -> 'a Node {
  |                                 ^^
```

So now the compiler tells me that it doesn't expect a lifetime parameter here, which seems contradictory to the message from before.
How can I express this structure correctly, where a Node has a reference to its parent, which lives at least as long as the child node itself? Is it only possible with `Rc` and if yes, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your defintion of node is

```
struct Node<'a>
```

but later on you don't provide that lifetime anymore. Your `new` signature must look like

```
fn new(parent: &'a Node) -> Node<'a>;
```

same with your struct definition

```
struct Node<'a> {
    parent: &'a Node<'a>,
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, that worked. But I still don't understand why there has to be a lifetime parameter in the angle brackets. Whats the difference between &Node<'a>, &'a Node and &'a Node<'a>. Does the lifetime parameter in the angle brackets just have to be there to satisfy the name of the type or does it mean anything?